# $\mathcal{L}\left\{t \int_0^t \sin \tau d \tau \right\}$

Tags: laplace-transform

Can someone give me a hint on how to solve this? I know I can do $\mathcal{L}\left\{t\cdot 1 \ast \sin t\right\}$

I'm not allowed to evaluate any integrals before transforming in this section.

Comment: $\int_0^t \sin \tau \, d\tau = 1-\cos t$

Comment: If that's the only way to do this, then this problem is misplaced. It clearly states in this section not to evaluate any integrals before transforming. :(

Comment: Hint: Multiplication of a function by $t$ then transforming has a special property...

Comment: @SeanRoberson Oh wait Am I meant to take $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$, so I have $t \cdot 1 \ast \sin t$ then I do the integral since I have now technically transformed? That seems like I cheated though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We shall use the following fact: If $(f, F)$ is a Laplace transform pair, then $$\mathcal{L} \left( tf(t) \right) = -F'(s) $$

[(use entry 30 here)](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/laplace_table.aspx). To that end, we let $f(t) = \int_0 ^\tau \sin \tau \ d\tau = (1 \star \sin(t))$ where $\star$ is the convolution operator. Now as the transform of a convolution is the product of its parts, we have $$\mathcal{L} \left(t (1 \star \sin (t) \right) =-\frac{d}{ds} \left( \frac{1}{s(s^2 + 1)} \right) $$

and from here it's just an application of the chain rule.

Comment: What is that identity called? $\mathcal{L}(tf(t)) = - F'(s)$ Is that the transform of a derivative? I now understand why I couldn't do this. My professor had us omit that section but the book went ahead and used this previous knowledge :P Thank you for the clarification @SeanRoberson

Comment: Time multiplication is the derivative of a transform. It does not have a special name. You can actually prove it via integration by parts.